# How to get current timestamp in nanoseconds in C++ without using chrono?

Tags: c++, ns-3

Since chrono is not supported in the Network Simulator -3 tool, I need to code in C++ without using chrono in order to get timestamp in nanoseconds.

Comment: Unanswerable question without target OS. Really tricky to get good time below microseconds, regardless of OS.

Comment: The answer is to use chrono; and if you cannot; to tweak your situation until you can. Chrono.

Comment: I need to get the fractional part of the seconds in UTCTime. I am looking for a way to do it. could someone suggest it!

Comment: Nanoseconds are difficult to get because many processors execute instructions in 10s to 100s of nanoseconds.  Reading the time from memory is a problem.  Will *milliseconds* or *microseconds* suffice?  Is there a need for *nanoseconds*?

Comment: Do you really need accuracy to 1E-9 seconds?  In most cases, milliseconds, 1E-3 will suffice.  Some applications may require 1E-6 or microseconds.  All of which are fractional parts of a second (so is 1/10 and 1/100).

Comment: You need to slow the time without slowing down the processor's execution, that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 64, I use POSIX

```
uint64_t MNS::getSystemNanosecond(void)
{
   const uint64_t NSPS = 1000000000;

   //struct timespec {  __time_t tv_sec;    long int tv_nsec;  };  -- total 8 bytes
   struct timespec ts;

   // CLOCK_REALTIME - system wide real time clock
   int status = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
   dtbAssert(0 == status);

   // to 8 byte     from   4 byte
   uint64_t uli_nsec = static_cast<uint64_t>(ts.tv_nsec);
   uint64_t uli_sec  = static_cast<uint64_t>(ts.tv_sec);

   uint64_t total_ns = uli_nsec + (uli_sec * NSPS);

   return(total_ns);
}
```

usage:

```
uint64_t startNS = MNS::getSystemNanosecond()

//... do stuff that takes time

uint64_t durationNS = MNS::getSystemNanosecond() - startNS;
```

Comment: On my older desktop,  the duration of the POSIX api "clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts)" is about  ~1600 ns.